# Text Transition Animation Isn't Working Properly, Is Glitching Instead

Tags: javascript

Currently this text animation function is producing a glitching effect upon manually resizing the screen.. Meaning it only transitions through each word when you shrink or expand the screen..

```
function animateText() {
        const $lastElement = $element.last(0);
        const $text = $lastElement.find('.js__text' , '.js__svg');
        const words = ['apart', 'out', 'shine']; // Array of words to animate

        let currentIndex = 0;

        setInterval(() => {
            $text.fadeOut(400, function() {
                $(this).text(words[currentIndex]);
            }).fadeIn(400);

            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % words.length;
        }, 2000);
    }


    // Automatically trigger the animation on page load
    $window.on('load', function() {
        animateText();
    });
}
```

Can anyone pinpoint what I've done wrong?